# Aligning Icomoon icons and getting correct shape

Tags: html, css, svg, icons

Kind of struggling to get my icons aligned and in the proper shape. I'm trying to achieve that in the footer I can print 4 social icons in line each in a cikel, and somewhere else on the page have 4 social icons appearing in line (flexbox), and square. However if I have the icons aligned as square buttons, than the cirkel become ovals.

What is the way to go and to have the icons styled independently and make sure they are responsive?

I just put all the code, a bit much, sorry for that.

```css
.social-container {
    display: flex;
    /* flex-direction: row; */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    min-height: 0%;
    flex: 0;
}
.social-container a {

}
/* @mixin svg {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    min-width: 0;
*/
a.svg, a.arrow {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    min-width: 0;
}
a.arrow {
    text-decoration-line: none;
}
a.svg {
    /* display: inline-flex; */
    text-decoration-line: none;
    position: relative;
}


a.svg:after {
  content: ""; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
}

.social-container a svg {
    height: 3vh;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.cirkel {
  background: #3b5998; 
  padding: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 99%;
  -moz-border-radius: 99%;
  border-radius: 99%;
}

.cirkel:hover {
    background-color: brown;
}
.square {
    display: inline-flex;
    /* height: 25px;
    line-height: 30px; */
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
   height: 30px;
   width: 80px;
   padding-top: 0.2em;
   padding-bottom: 0.2em;
   padding-right: 0.2em;
}
.square.fb-background {
    background: #3b5998;
}
.square.tw-background {
    background-color: #4da7de;
}
.square.pi-background {
    background-color: #b51205;
}
.square.gp-background {
    background-color: #dd4b39;
}

.flex-item {
    height: 5%;
}
.name{
  font-size: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}

/* styling individual icons */
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  stroke-width: 0;
  stroke: currentColor;
  fill: currentColor;

} 


/* obsolete styls */
.access-label {
text-decoration: none;
}


/* ==========================================
Single-colored icons can be modified like so:
.icon-name {
  font-size: 32px;
  color: red;
}
========================================== */

.icon-home3 {
    color:blue;
}
.icon-arrow-left2 {
    width: 30px;
    min-height: 0vh;
}
.icon-arrow-left2:hover {
    background-color:#013e75;
    color: white;
}

.icon-facebook:before {
    content:'\e041';
}
/* .icon-facebook {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
}  */

.icon-facebook {
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
   /* width: 20%; 
   height: 2%; */
   padding: 3px;
} 
.icon-facebook:hover {
    background-color: #2a4784;
}
.icon-google-plus:before {
    content:'\e042';
}
.icon-google-plus {

   /* width: 20%; * /
   height: 2%; */
   color: white;
   font-size: 20px;
}
.icon-google-plus:hover {
    background-color: #c93725;
}

.icon-linkedin2:before {
    content:'\e049';
}
.icon-linkedin2 {
    background-color: #3371b7;
    color: white;
   /* width: 20%; */
   height: 2%;
}
.icon-linkedin2:hover {
    background-color: #1f5da3;
}
.icon-pinterest2:before {
    content:'\e043';
}
.icon-pinterest2 {
    color: white;
   /* width: 20%; */
   padding: 3px;
   height: 2%;
   font-size: 20px;
}
.icon-pinterest:hover {

}

.icon-price-tag {
    width: 20px;
    height: 25px;
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

/* same styling icons used in text heading tag <H4> */
.icon-price-tags, .icon-camera, .icon-bubbles {
    color: white;
}
.icon-sailing-boat-water {
    color: blueviolet;
}
.icon-price-tags, .icon-camera, .icon-bubbles {
    height: 25px;
    display: inline;
    padding-top: 4px;
    width: 30px;
    min-height: 0vh;
}
.icon-rss:before {
    content:'\e00b';
}
.icon-rss {
   /* width: 20%; */
   height: 2%;
   padding: 3px;
    background-color: #f26109;
    color: white;
}
.icon-rss:hover {
    background-color: #de4d00;
}
.icon-search {
    color: #ccc;
}
.icon-search:hover {
    color: blueviolet;
}
.icon-twitter:before {
    content:'\e040';
}

.icon-twitter {

    color: white;
    /* width: 20%; */
    height: 2%;
    padding: 3px;
   font-size: 20px;
}
.icon-twitter:hover {
    background-color: #3993ca;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>IcoMoon - SVG Icons</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo-files/demo.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo-files/probeersel.css">
    <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="SVG/cssfolder-SVG_SPRITE/iconizr-svg-sprite.css" -->
    <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" -->
    </head>
    <body>
    <svg aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; width: 0; height: 0; overflow: hidden;" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> <defs> <symbol id="icon-sailing-boat-water" viewbox="0 0 32 32"> 
    <title>sailing-boat-water</title>
    <path d="M21.671 23h0.329c2.209 0 3.999-1.795 3.999-4h-10v-15h-1v15h-10c0 0.876 0.282 1.686 0.759 2.345 3.661-1.772 7.586-1.975 11.486 0.219 1.515 0.852 2.993 1.312 4.426 1.436v0 0zM26 18h-9v-9l9 9zM8 9.5c-3 5-3 8.5-3 8.5h9c0 0-1-1.5-1-6s1-8 1-8c0 0-3 0.5-6 5.5v0zM3 25c0.432-0.319 0.901-0.634 1.405-0.934 4.032-2.406 8.441-2.965 12.82-0.502 4.021 2.262 7.786 1.761 11.12-0.452 0.623-0.414 1.177-0.857 1.655-1.299v1.322c-0.341 0.277-0.709 0.549-1.102 0.81-3.622 2.405-7.778 2.957-12.164 0.491-4.022-2.262-8.065-1.75-11.817 0.489-0.713 0.425-1.353 0.881-1.911 1.336-0.002 0.002-0.004 0.003-0.006 0.005v-1.266zM5.979 26.232c3.592-1.665 7.43-1.813 11.245 0.333 3.481 1.958 6.771 1.846 9.755 0.344v1.109c-3.143 1.433-6.616 1.46-10.245-0.581-3.645-2.050-7.307-1.822-10.755-0.094v-1.11z"></path> </symbol> <symbol id="icon-home3" viewbox="0 0 32 32"> 
    <title>home3</title>
    <path d="M32 19l-6-6v-9h-4v5l-6-6-16 16v1h4v10h10v-6h4v6h10v-10h4z"></path> </symbol> <symbol id="icon-camera" viewbox="0 0 32 32"> 
    <title>camera</title>
    <path d="M9.5 19c0 3.59 2.91 6.5 6.5 6.5s6.5-2.91 6.5-6.5-2.91-6.5-6.5-6.5-6.5 2.91-6.5 6.5zM30 8h-7c-0.5-2-1-4-3-4h-8c-2 0-2.5 2-3 4h-7c-1.1 0-2 0.9-2 2v18c0 1.1 0.9 2 2 2h28c1.1 0 2-0.9 2-2v-18c0-1.1-0.9-2-2-2zM16 27.875c-4.902 0-8.875-3.973-8.875-8.875s3.973-8.875 8.875-8.875c4.902 0 8.875 3.973 8.875 8.875s-3.973 8.875-8.875 8.875zM30 14h-4v-2h4v2z"></path> </symbol> <symbol id="icon-file-text" viewbox="0 0 32 32"> 
    <title>file-text</title>
    <path d="M27 0h-24c-1.65 0-3 1.35-3 3v26c0 1.65 1.35 3 3 3h24c1.65 0 3-1.35 3-3v-26c0-1.65-1.35-3-3-3zM26 28h-22v-24h22v24zM8 14h14v2h-14zM8 18h14v2h-14zM8 22h14v2h-14zM8 10h14v2h-14z"></path> </symbol> <symbol id="icon-profile" viewbox="0 0 32 32"> 
    <title>profile</title>
    <path d="M27 0h-24c-1.65 0-3 1.35-3 3v26c0 1.65 1.35 3 3 3h24c1.65 0 3-1.35 3-3v-26c0-1.65-1.35-3-3-3zM26 28h-22v-24h22v24zM8 18h14v2h-14zM8 22h14v2h-14zM10 9c0-1.657 1.343-3 3-3s3 1.343 3 3c0 1.657-1.343 3-3 3s-3-1.343-3-3zM15 12h-4c-1.65 0-3 0.9-3 2v2h10v-2c0-1.1-1.35-2-3-2z"></path> </symbol> <symbol id="icon-price-tag" viewbox="0 0 32 32"> 
    <title>price-tag</title>
    <path d="M30.5 0h-12c-0.825 0-1.977 0.477-2.561 1.061l-14.879 14.879c-0.583 0.583-0.583 1.538 0 2.121l12.879 12.879c0.583 0.583 1.538 0.583 2.121 0l14.879-14.879c0.583-0.583 1.061-1.736 1.061-2.561v-12c0-0.825-0.675-1.5-1.5-1.5zM23 12c-1.657 0-3-1.343-3-3s1.343-3 3-3 3 1.343 3 3-1.343 3-3 3z"></path> </symbol> <symbol id="icon-price-tags" viewbox="0 0 40 32"> 
    <title>price-tags</title>
    <path d="M38.5 0h-12c-0.825 0-1.977 0.477-2.561 1.061l-14.879 14.879c-0.583 0.583-0.583 1.538 0 2.121l12.879 12.879c0.583 0.583 1.538 0.583 2.121 0l14.879-14.879c0.583-0.583 1.061-1.736 1.061-2.561v-12c0-0.825-0.675-1.5-1.5-1.5zM31 12c-1.657 0-3-1.343-3-3s1.343-3 3-3 3 1.343 3 3-1.343 3-3 3z"></path> <path d="M4 17l17-17h-2.5c-0.825 0-1.977 0.477-2.561 1.061l-14.879 14.879c-0.583 0.583-0.583 1.538 0 2.121l12.879 12.879c0.583 0.583 1.538 0.583 2.121 0l0.939-0.939-13-13z"></path> </symbol> <symbol id="icon-bubbles" viewbox="0 0 36 32"> 
    <title>bubbles</title>
    <path d="M34 28.161c0 1.422 0.813 2.653 2 3.256v0.498c-0.332 0.045-0.671 0.070-1.016 0.070-2.125 0-4.042-0.892-5.398-2.321-0.819 0.218-1.688 0.336-2.587 0.336-4.971 0-9-3.582-9-8s4.029-8 9-8c4.971 0 9 3.582 9 8 0 1.73-0.618 3.331-1.667 4.64-0.213 0.463-0.333 0.979-0.333 1.522zM16 0c8.702 0 15.781 5.644 15.995 12.672-1.537-0.685-3.237-1.047-4.995-1.047-2.986 0-5.807 1.045-7.942 2.943-2.214 1.968-3.433 4.607-3.433 7.432 0 1.396 0.298 2.747 0.867 3.993-0.163 0.004-0.327 0.007-0.492 0.007-0.849 0-1.682-0.054-2.495-0.158-3.437 3.437-7.539 4.053-11.505 4.144v-0.841c2.142-1.049 4-2.961 4-5.145 0-0.305-0.024-0.604-0.068-0.897-3.619-2.383-5.932-6.024-5.932-10.103 0-7.18 7.163-13 16-13z"></path> </symbol> <symbol id="icon-spinner3" viewbox="0 0 32 32"> 
    <title>spinner3</title>
    <path d="M16 9.472c-1.030 0-1.865-0.835-1.865-1.865v-5.596c0-1.030 0.835-1.865 1.865-1.865s1.865 0.835 1.865 1.865v5.596c0 1.030-0.835 1.865-1.865 1.865z"></path> <path d="M16 31.155c-0.644 0-1.166-0.522-1.166-1.166v-5.596c0-0.644 0.522-1.166 1.166-1.166s1.166 0.522 1.166 1.166v5.596c0 0.644-0.522 1.166-1.166 1.166z"></path> <path d="M11.805 10.48c-0.604 0-1.192-0.314-1.516-0.875l-2.798-4.846c-0.483-0.836-0.196-1.906 0.64-2.389s1.906-0.196 2.389 0.64l2.798 4.846c0.483 0.836 0.196 1.906-0.64 2.389-0.275 0.159-0.576 0.235-0.873 0.235z"></path> <path d="M22.995 29.164c-0.363 0-0.715-0.188-0.91-0.525l-2.798-4.846c-0.29-0.502-0.118-1.143 0.384-1.433s1.143-0.118 1.433 0.384l2.798 4.846c0.29 0.502 0.118 1.143-0.384 1.433-0.165 0.095-0.346 0.141-0.524 0.141z"></path> <path d="M8.729 13.436c-0.277 0-0.557-0.070-0.814-0.219l-4.846-2.798c-0.781-0.451-1.048-1.449-0.597-2.229s1.449-1.048 2.229-0.597l4.846 2.798c0.781 0.451 1.048 1.449 0.597 2.229-0.302 0.524-0.851 0.816-1.415 0.816z"></path> <path d="M28.114 23.927c-0.158 0-0.319-0.040-0.465-0.125l-4.846-2.798c-0.446-0.258-0.599-0.828-0.341-1.274s0.828-0.599 1.274-0.341l4.846 2.798c0.446 0.258 0.599 0.828 0.341 1.274-0.173 0.299-0.486 0.466-0.809 0.466z"></path> <path d="M7.607 17.515h-5.596c-0.837 0-1.516-0.678-1.516-1.515s0.678-1.515 1.516-1.515h5.596c0.837 0 1.516 0.678 1.516 1.515s-0.678 1.515-1.516 1.515z"></path> <path d="M29.989 16.933c-0 0 0 0 0 0h-5.596c-0.515-0-0.933-0.418-0.933-0.933s0.418-0.933 0.933-0.933c0 0 0 0 0 0h5.596c0.515 0 0.933 0.418 0.933 0.933s-0.418 0.933-0.933 0.933z"></path> <path d="M3.886 24.394c-0.483 0-0.954-0.251-1.213-0.7-0.386-0.669-0.157-1.525 0.512-1.911l4.846-2.798c0.669-0.387 1.525-0.157 1.911 0.512s0.157 1.525-0.512 1.911l-4.846 2.798c-0.22 0.127-0.461 0.188-0.698 0.188z"></path> <path d="M23.27 12.736c-0.322 0-0.636-0.167-0.809-0.466-0.258-0.446-0.105-1.016 0.341-1.274l4.846-2.798c0.446-0.257 1.016-0.105 1.274 0.341s0.105 1.016-0.341 1.274l-4.846 2.798c-0.147 0.085-0.307 0.125-0.465 0.125z"></path> <path d="M9.004 29.397c-0.218 0-0.438-0.055-0.64-0.172-0.613-0.354-0.823-1.138-0.469-1.752l2.798-4.846c0.354-0.613 1.138-0.823 1.752-0.469s0.823 1.138 0.469 1.752l-2.798 4.846c-0.237 0.411-0.668 0.641-1.112 0.641z"></path> <path d="M20.196 9.664c-0.158 0-0.319-0.040-0.465-0.125-0.446-0.258-0.599-0.828-0.341-1.274l2.798-4.846c0.258-0.446 0.828-0.599 1.274-0.341s0.599 0.828 0.341 1.274l-2.798 4.846c-0.173 0.299-0.486 0.466-0.809 0.466z"></path> </symbol> <symbol id="icon-search" viewbox="0 0 32 32"> 
    <title>search</title>
    <path d="M31.008 27.231l-7.58-6.447c-0.784-0.705-1.622-1.029-2.299-0.998 1.789-2.096 2.87-4.815 2.87-7.787 0-6.627-5.373-12-12-12s-12 5.373-12 12 5.373 12 12 12c2.972 0 5.691-1.081 7.787-2.87-0.031 0.677 0.293 1.515 0.998 2.299l6.447 7.58c1.104 1.226 2.907 1.33 4.007 0.23s0.997-2.903-0.23-4.007zM12 20c-4.418 0-8-3.582-8-8s3.582-8 8-8 8 3.582 8 8-3.582 8-8 8z"></path> </symbol> <symbol id="icon-arrow-up2" viewbox="0 0 32 32"> 
    <title>arrow-up2</title>
    <path d="M27.414 12.586l-10-10c-0.781-0.781-2.047-0.781-2.828 0l-10 10c-0.781 0.781-0.781 2.047 0 2.828s2.047 0.781 2.828 0l6.586-6.586v19.172c0 1.105 0.895 2 2 2s2-0.895 2-2v-19.172l6.586 6.586c0.39 0.39 0.902 0.586 1.414 0.586s1.024-0.195 1.414-0.586c0.781-0.781 0.781-2.047 0-2.828z"></path> </symbol> <symbol id="icon-arrow-right2" viewbox="0 0 32 32"> 
    <title>arrow-right2</title>
    <path d="M19.414 27.414l10-10c0.781-0.781 0.781-2.047 0-2.828l-10-10c-0.781-0.781-2.047-0.781-2.828 0s-0.781 2.047 0 2.828l6.586 6.586h-19.172c-1.105 0-2 0.895-2 2s0.895 2 2 2h19.172l-6.586 6.586c-0.39 0.39-0.586 0.902-0.586 1.414s0.195 1.024 0.586 1.414c0.781 0.781 2.047 0.781 2.828 0z"></path> </symbol> <symbol id="icon-arrow-left2" viewbox="0 0 32 32"> 
    <title>arrow-left2</title>
    <path d="M12.586 27.414l-10-10c-0.781-0.781-0.781-2.047 0-2.828l10-10c0.781-0.781 2.047-0.781 2.828 0s0.781 2.047 0 2.828l-6.586 6.586h19.172c1.105 0 2 0.895 2 2s-0.895 2-2 2h-19.172l6.586 6.586c0.39 0.39 0.586 0.902 0.586 1.414s-0.195 1.024-0.586 1.414c-0.781 0.781-2.047 0.781-2.828 0z"></path> </symbol> <symbol id="icon-google-plus" viewbox="0 0 32 32"> 
    <title>google-plus</title>
    <path d="M10.181 14.294v3.494h5.775c-0.231 1.5-1.744 4.394-5.775 4.394-3.475 0-6.313-2.881-6.313-6.431s2.838-6.431 6.313-6.431c1.981 0 3.3 0.844 4.056 1.569l2.762-2.662c-1.775-1.656-4.075-2.662-6.819-2.662-5.631 0.006-10.181 4.556-10.181 10.188s4.55 10.181 10.181 10.181c5.875 0 9.775-4.131 9.775-9.95 0-0.669-0.075-1.181-0.163-1.688h-9.613z"></path> <path d="M32 14h-3v-3h-3v3h-3v3h3v3h3v-3h3z"></path> </symbol> <symbol id="icon-facebook" viewbox="0 0 32 32"> 
    <title>facebook</title>
    <path d="M19 6h5v-6h-5c-3.86 0-7 3.14-7 7v3h-4v6h4v16h6v-16h5l1-6h-6v-3c0-0.542 0.458-1 1-1z"></path> </symbol> <symbol id="icon-twitter" viewbox="0 0 32 32"> 
    <title>twitter</title>
    <path d="M32 7.075c-1.175 0.525-2.444 0.875-3.769 1.031 1.356-0.813 2.394-2.1 2.887-3.631-1.269 0.75-2.675 1.3-4.169 1.594-1.2-1.275-2.906-2.069-4.794-2.069-3.625 0-6.563 2.938-6.563 6.563 0 0.512 0.056 1.012 0.169 1.494-5.456-0.275-10.294-2.888-13.531-6.862-0.563 0.969-0.887 2.1-0.887 3.3 0 2.275 1.156 4.287 2.919 5.463-1.075-0.031-2.087-0.331-2.975-0.819 0 0.025 0 0.056 0 0.081 0 3.181 2.263 5.838 5.269 6.437-0.55 0.15-1.131 0.231-1.731 0.231-0.425 0-0.831-0.044-1.237-0.119 0.838 2.606 3.263 4.506 6.131 4.563-2.25 1.762-5.075 2.813-8.156 2.813-0.531 0-1.050-0.031-1.569-0.094 2.913 1.869 6.362 2.95 10.069 2.95 12.075 0 18.681-10.006 18.681-18.681 0-0.287-0.006-0.569-0.019-0.85 1.281-0.919 2.394-2.075 3.275-3.394z"></path> </symbol> <symbol id="icon-rss" viewbox="0 0 32 32"> 
    <title>rss</title>
    <path d="M4.259 23.467c-2.35 0-4.259 1.917-4.259 4.252 0 2.349 1.909 4.244 4.259 4.244 2.358 0 4.265-1.895 4.265-4.244-0-2.336-1.907-4.252-4.265-4.252zM0.005 10.873v6.133c3.993 0 7.749 1.562 10.577 4.391 2.825 2.822 4.384 6.595 4.384 10.603h6.16c-0-11.651-9.478-21.127-21.121-21.127zM0.012 0v6.136c14.243 0 25.836 11.604 25.836 25.864h6.152c0-17.64-14.352-32-31.988-32z"></path> </symbol> <symbol id="icon-linkedin2" viewbox="0 0 32 32"> 
    <title>linkedin2</title>
    <path d="M12 12h5.535v2.837h0.079c0.77-1.381 2.655-2.837 5.464-2.837 5.842 0 6.922 3.637 6.922 8.367v9.633h-5.769v-8.54c0-2.037-0.042-4.657-3.001-4.657-3.005 0-3.463 2.218-3.463 4.509v8.688h-5.767v-18z"></path> <path d="M2 12h6v18h-6v-18z"></path> <path d="M8 7c0 1.657-1.343 3-3 3s-3-1.343-3-3c0-1.657 1.343-3 3-3s3 1.343 3 3z"></path> </symbol> <symbol id="icon-pinterest2" viewbox="0 0 32 32"> 
    <title>pinterest2</title>
    <path d="M16 0c-8.825 0-16 7.175-16 16s7.175 16 16 16 16-7.175 16-16-7.175-16-16-16zM16 29.863c-1.431 0-2.806-0.219-4.106-0.619 0.563-0.919 1.412-2.431 1.725-3.631 0.169-0.65 0.863-3.294 0.863-3.294 0.45 0.863 1.775 1.594 3.175 1.594 4.181 0 7.194-3.844 7.194-8.625 0-4.581-3.738-8.006-8.544-8.006-5.981 0-9.156 4.019-9.156 8.387 0 2.031 1.081 4.563 2.813 5.369 0.262 0.125 0.4 0.069 0.463-0.188 0.044-0.194 0.281-1.131 0.387-1.575 0.031-0.137 0.019-0.262-0.094-0.4-0.575-0.694-1.031-1.975-1.031-3.162 0-3.056 2.313-6.019 6.256-6.019 3.406 0 5.788 2.319 5.788 5.637 0 3.75-1.894 6.35-4.356 6.35-1.363 0-2.381-1.125-2.050-2.506 0.394-1.65 1.15-3.425 1.15-4.613 0-1.063-0.569-1.95-1.756-1.95-1.394 0-2.506 1.438-2.506 3.369 0 1.225 0.412 2.056 0.412 2.056s-1.375 5.806-1.625 6.887c-0.281 1.2-0.169 2.881-0.050 3.975-5.156-2.012-8.813-7.025-8.813-12.9 0-7.656 6.206-13.863 13.862-13.863s13.863 6.206 13.863 13.863c0 7.656-6.206 13.863-13.863 13.863z"></path> </symbol> </defs> </svg> 
    <header class="bgc1 clearfix">
     <div class="mhl">
      <p>
       SVG Icons - Generated by <a href="https://icomoon.io/app">IcoMoon</a>
      </p>
     </div>
    </header>
    <a href="https://website-url" title="Latest News"> <svg class="icon icon-sailing-boat-water" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false"> <use xlink:href="#icon-sailing-boat-water"></use> </svg> </a> <br />
    <br />
    <span class="cirkel"><svg preserveaspectratio="none" class="icon icon-facebook"><use xlink:href="#icon-facebook"></use></svg></span> <br />
    <br />
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={$canonical}" target="_blank" class="svg"> <span class="cirkel"><svg preserveaspectratio="none" class="icon icon-facebook"><use xlink:href="#icon-facebook"></use></svg></span> </a> <br />
    <br />
    <span class="social-container" style="width: 400px;"> <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={$canonical}" target="_blank" class="svg"> <span class="square fb-background"><svg preserveaspectratio="none" class="icon icon-facebook"><use xlink:href="#icon-facebook"></use></svg></span> </a> <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url={canonical}&amp;text={title}&amp;hashtags=$hashtags" target="popup" onclick="window.open('https://www.twitter.com','name','width=600,height=400')" class="svg"> <span class="square tw-background"><svg preserveaspectratio="none" class="icon icon-twitter"><use xlink:href="#icon-twitter"></use></svg></span> </a> <a href="javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement('script');e.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');e.setAttribute('charset','UTF-8');e.setAttribute('src','http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r='+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());" class="svg"> <span class="square pi-background"><svg preserveaspectratio="none" class="icon icon-pinterest2"><use xlink:href="#icon-pinterest2"></use></svg></span> </a> <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={$canonical}" target="_blank" class="svg"> <span class="square gp-background"><svg preserveaspectratio="none" class="icon icon-google-plus"><use xlink:href="#icon-google-plus"></use></svg></span> </a> 
    </span> 
    <p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I've edited your question to include a snippet to help anyone else viewing your question see what's going on.

Might I suggest you take a bit of time to reduce the amount of HTML and CSS you have included to the bare minimum to replicate your issue. You are far more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with your suggestion. Because I'm not sure what the root cause is, and wanted to for come someone is willing to help, but missing background, I thought to give as much detail as possible. For future questions I'll reduce the amount of code.